# 'Client secret validation failed for client' error on identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to get an access token from my Identity Server 4 with client_credentials , i think i almost finished the Google pages with my search and i found nothing. So please:

**This is my GetClients method**

[image]My PostMan Request, in the header i have only the `Content_Type` which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]

And the error :

[image]

Comment: Anyway, https isn't the issue, i'm getting the same error on HTTP too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You started with the correct row of code: `"secret".Sha256()` but later forgot it.
Try the following:

```cs
var secret = new Secret {Value = "test".Sha512()};
ClientSecrets = new[] {secret};
```

The secret must be hashed.

Briefly tested with

> curl https://localhost:5001/connect/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=azure-client-id&client_secret=test"

and

> curl https://localhost:5001/connect/token -H "Authorization: Basic YXp1cmUtY2xpZW50LWlkOnRlc3Q=" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193732/discussion-on-answer-by-d-f-client-secret-validation-failed-for-client-error-o).