# Client secret validation failed for client

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, identityserver4

[image: Client Configuration in Mongo DB]

[image: Postman Request]

I am unable to get token for my api using the set up as shown in the image.  As you can see the hashed value does not have a '+'. The unhashed password is 'ecret'. That is not a typo. I have also tried RequirePkce to false. I have turned on logging for identity server but it has only limited information. There is a single message.

```
Client secret validation failed for client:api.client.
```

I have also seen [SO entry here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236558/client-secret-validation-failed-for-client-error-on-identity-server-4/56237403).

Comment: How was the stored hashed secret ("/98EG...") generated in the first place?

Comment: in c# 
Secret s = new Secret("ecret".Sha256());

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to figure out. The samples are behind the development. Documentation may be little more updated.
While searching for other authorization mechanisms, it occurred to me that HTTP had an authorization header as in the image.

[image]